# Matrix math equation not splitting over two lines

Tags: align, amsmath, matrices

I am using amsmath and the `\\` to split over lines as the learn latex website suggested. However, my equation does not seem to split.

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 1 \\
        b & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r \\
        t
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r \\
        t
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 1 \\
        b & 1
    \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\end{equation}
```

This is what it looks like rendered for me: [image: rendered]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `equation` use `align`. Then use `&=` insyead of `=` so that the equals signs are aligned. If you don't want the lines to be numbered, use `align*`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does the "learn latex" website say anyhing about multi-line math environments such as `split`, `aligned`, and `multline`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "split"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\begin{pmatrix}
        a & 1 \\
        b & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r \\
        t
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y
    \end{pmatrix}
\\
&
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r \\
        t
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 1 \\
        b & 1
    \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for *not* aligning the equations on the `=` symbols?

Comment: @Mico is there a reason to do alignment? did the user request alignment?

Comment: You asked (rhetorically, I assume), "is there a reason to do alignment?" Well, the  solution you posted performs alignment as well -- along the left-hand edges. If one wants to argue that because the OP didn't indicate explicitly whether or not alignment should be performed, no alignment should be performed, one ought to be using a `gathered` environment, not a `split` environment, which ends up centering both equations.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. @Mico thanks for the alignment suggestion as well, will be useful later. Unrelated question, how to get matrices to render like yours which has curvier parenthesis? Mines look like the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @l3utterfly -  Judging by the screenshot you posted, you appear to have increased line spacing somehow in your document. Unfortunately, you posted just a code snippet, not a fully compilable example. As you've given no information about how exactly you've increased the line spacing, it's difficult to answer your question with any degree of specificity. For sure, any good answer will have to reduce the line spacing in the equations. Do please provide the missing information.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was the "arraystretch" command at the top of my doc which caused this.

Comment: @l3utterfly - By all means, get rid of the instruction that modifies the `\arraystretch` macro.

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there: Just encase the math material in a `split` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package, which also provides the `pmatrix` environment) and change both instances of `=` to `&=` to indicate where the alignment should be performed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 1 \\ b & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r \\ t
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\ y
    \end{pmatrix} \\ % line break
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r \\ t
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &=
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & 1 \\ b & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{\!-1}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
    x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```